# what is the most frequent error in python for a beginner?

Tags: python

What do you think is the most frequent errors or pitfalls a beginner may encounter when he use python?

Comment: shouldn't this be community wiki? *if not, ignore my ignorance*

Comment: In fact Users can not mark questions wiki anymore, across the network. see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67039/what-can-we-do-to-make-community-wiki-better/67192#67192

Comment: Right, thanks for giving me that.

Answer (score 2):

*Forgetting the `self` keyword in classes.*

Either in method declaration and/or when referencing class members (specially for someone coming from `.NET/Java/..` world where "equivalent" `this` keyword can be omitted).

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be:

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: I think that error suits every programming language :P

Comment: Yea I giggled a bit when I thought of it. It's totally the right answer though ;)

Answer (score 1):

That could be `IndentationError` resulting from incorrect mix of tabs and spaces in code and/or incorrect code formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean errors or pitfalls? For the later I'd say: passing mutable objects as default values:

```
def foo(bar=[]):
    bar.append("foobar")
    return bar

foo()
foo() # Wait! Why am I getting ['foobar', 'foobar'] here? D'Oh ;)
```

Comment: I'm not very fluent in English what I mean is the different problems a beginner can encounter and may solve by asking Stack Overflow by example.

Comment: @Xavier Ok, then I think my answer fits.

Answer (score 0):

After answering twice the same question. It looks like the more surprising thing it's when the script is named like the module they want to import.